# SQL - INNER JOIN of multiple tables is throwing a syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I've done some searching, and re-worked my SQL a number of times based on examples here and from other online sources, but every time I run this SQL I get the same "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax" error.

I'm trying to join four tables using INNER join, and they should always have matching data to key off of (i.e. there should always be one full row for every valid token/token_id). I'm using MySQL version 5.7.26
Here is the query I am trying to run:

```
   SELECT
    i.name AS invitee_name,
    c.first_name AS child_first,
    c.last_name AS child_last,
    s.invite_status,
    c.avatar
  FROM
    Invites AS i, Tokens AS t, Children AS c, Invite_Statuses AS s
  WHERE
    t.token = sdie02d
  INNER JOIN
    t ON t.token_id = i.token_id
  INNER JOIN
    c ON c.child_id = i.child_id
  INNER JOIN
    s ON s.status_id = i.status_id
```

The full error I receive (every time) is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN
    t ON t.token_id = i.token_id
  INNER JOIN
    c ON c.child_id ' at line 11
```

The tables look like this:

```
Invites
+---------+----------+----------+-----------+---------------+----------+
| user_id | child_id | token_id | status_id |     email     |   name   |
+---------+----------+----------+-----------+---------------+----------+
|       9 |        2 |        1 |         1 | a@example.com | John Doe |
|       9 |        3 |        2 |         1 | b@example.com | Jane Doe |
+---------+----------+----------+-----------+---------------+----------+
```

```
Tokens

+----------+---------+
| token_id |  token  |
+----------+---------+
|        1 | 93kd8i0 |
|        2 | sdie02d |
|        3 | fsj2d9c |
+----------+---------+
```

```
Children
+----------+------------+-----------+--------+
| child_id | first_name | last_name | avatar |
+----------+------------+-----------+--------+
|        1 | Timmy      | Johnson   |      4 |
|        2 | Jenny      | Smith     |     32 |
|        3 | Jake       | Jones     |     12 |
+----------+------------+-----------+--------+
```

```
Invite_Statuses
+-----------+---------------+
| status_id | invite_status |
+-----------+---------------+
|         1 | invited       |
|         2 | accepted      |
|         3 | rejected      |
+-----------+---------------+
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Don't put the joined tables' names/aliases in the `where`. Put them in the `inner join`. e.g. `inner join Tokens as t on t.token_id = i.token_id`. Only the first/'main' table should be named/aliased in the `where`.

Comment: At this point, 5 minutes in the company of any basic introductory book or tutorial would be beneficial

Comment: where goes after inner join

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple errors here

```
   SELECT
    i.name AS invitee_name,
    c.first_name AS child_first,
    c.last_name AS child_last,
    s.invite_status,
    c.avatar
  FROM
    Invites AS i
  INNER JOIN Tokens AS t
    ON t.token_id = i.token_id
  INNER JOIN Children AS c
    ON c.child_id = i.child_id
  INNER JOIN Invite_Statuses AS s
    ON s.status_id = i.status_id
  WHERE
    t.token = qme34jh
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at examples of other inner joins, try putting the 'where' statement at the end and see if that works?

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

you need to add '' in where clause condition 'qme34j'

```
declare @Tokens Table ( token_id int, token varchar(100))
declare @Children Table ( child_id int, first_name varchar(100), last_name varchar(100), avatar int)
declare @Invite_Statuses table  (status_id int, invite_status  varchar(100))

SELECT
 i.name AS invitee_name,
 c.first_name AS child_first,
 c.last_name AS child_last,
 s.invite_status,
 c.avatar
FROM
 @Invites AS i
INNER JOIN @Tokens AS t
 ON t.token_id = i.token_id
INNER JOIN @Children AS c
 ON c.child_id = i.child_id
INNER JOIN @Invite_Statuses AS s
 ON s.status_id = i.status_id
WHERE
 t.token = 'qme34jh'
```